# Whenever I restart system it shows 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in kafka to spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

This is my following code for getting data from kafka to spark streaming
Firstly it was running, but when I restarted system it is again showing the following error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 5: invalid start byte

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.message_serializer import MessageSerializer

schema_registry_client = CachedSchemaRegistryClient(url='http://0.0.0.0:8081')
serializer = MessageSerializer(schema_registry_client)
sc = SparkContext()
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)



# def decoder(s):
#     decoded_message = serializer.decode_message(s)
#     return decoded_message

kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["demo.Appointment_Attendance.Patient"], {
                                "metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092"}, 
                                 valueDecoder=serializer.decode_message)
keyDecoder=lambda x: x, valueDecoder=lambda x: x)
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
lines.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Well, `0.0.0.0:8081` isn't a real address. Did you mean `localhost:8081`? Can you get the messages without your decoder? Then map them later?

Comment: I changed it to localhost:8081. I am not getting the message without decoder @cricket_007

Comment: if I am passing decoder like this:

`kvs=KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc["demo.Appointment_Attendance.Patient"], {"metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092"}, keyDecoder=lambda x: x,valueDecoder=lambda x: x)`            


I am getting output like this:
`b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x02\xa6\x01\nMayur\x02\xd2\xd5\xc8\xc24\x02\xc8\x0b\x08male\x08demoT\xf0\xf1\xd9\xdf\x0b\x00 mysql-bin.000020\xce$\x00\x00\x02\x04\x02,Appointment_Attendance\x02\x0ePatient\x02c\x02\xba\xd6\xa1\xd6\xe3['`

How to convert this to readable format

Comment: Something like `kvs.mapValues(lambda v: serializer.decode_message(v))`

Comment: ok Thnx it worked

Answer (score 0):

0x98 is cyrillic letter И in utf-8, actually this letter is represented by bytes 0xD0,0x98
In charset windows-1251 0x98 is described as undefined.
Do you have access to the string with 'И'? Can you change it to small letter 'и'? Another option is to substitute 'И' to some unique marker like ==CYR_I== and later carry out reverse substitution.

Comment: I don't think this is important about what character it is. The 5th byte is the content of the data https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format

Answer (score 0):

Moving comment to answer...

First try just consuming raw bytes

topic = ssc["demo.Appointment_Attendance.Patient"]
   kvs=KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(topic, {"metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092"})

If that works, then try to deserailize in a later stage via map / mapValues

```
kvs.mapValues(lambda v: serializer.decode_message(v))
```

Once that works, try moving back to using the valueDecoder